# Sprint batch fault tolerance issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch for my project, my requirement is to write the error record in a file.
I used spring batch fault tolerant and skip policy like any exception can be skippable. What my issue is i have only 1 record in file and it is failing so i'm expecting only 1 record to be written in error file but i'm getting 2(same) records in error file. When i googled it is known that when you configure fault tolerant in spring batch when error occurs it will retry the error record again. How to stop this behaviour and to write only 1 record in error file.

Ex: Step configuration of spring batch(below is just the raw code)

```
    public Step mainstep()
    {
     stepbuilder.get("step").<Employee,Employee>chunk(2)
.reader()
.processor()
.writer()
.faulttolerant()
.skippolicy(new AlwaysskipItemskippolicy())
.build;
    }
```

i'm writting error file try catch block in reader class. Using file output stream i'm writing. I have only 1 record to process in file, but when i see the error file i'm getting the same records writing twice.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be writing invalid records in a component other than a `SkipListener`. The behaviour you are describing should not happen if you use a `SkipListener` in which you write invalid records to a file.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, Thanks for the reply, i first tried with skipListener itself, as it is writing the same record 2 times in skiplistener, i tried in component  even the same is happening,  in google i found that when ever an error record occures in skip it will retry again

Comment: The skip listener will be called only when all retry attempts are exhausted, so it should be called only once at the end. If the record is written twice in the file, then the code that writes that record to the file is not in the skip listener, but elsewhere.